# Foreman/Puppet: Cert request is signed but host does not appear

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, foreman, puppet-foreman

at the moment I'm having a problem adding hosts to foreman.

I added a client installing puppet from repo (according to the documentation of puppet) and configuring it.

The puppet.conf of a client:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN 
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY


[agent]
server = puppet.example.com
```

Well, if I start puppet via `systemctl start puppet` the cert request is shown on `puppet.example.com`; if I sign the request the host does not appear on foreman's hosts-page, where currently 13 other hosts are shown.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your puppet client does not seem to automatically try to sync with the puppet server, adding: "runinterval = 1800" to your client config under the [agent] section will sync puppet every 3 minutes, otherwise to manually run a sync, run "puppet agent -t" after the 1st synchronization after the cert was signed it should show up.